# Why is this a conflict-free memory bank access?

Tags: memory, cuda, gpgpu

Here is an image taken from the CUDA C Programming Guide:

[image]

The guide says that this is an example of a *Conflict-free access since threads 3, 4, 6, 7 and 9 access the same word within bank 5*.

I don't quite understand why is this conflict-free, since not only threads 3, 4, 6, 7 and 9 access the same work within same bank (shouldn't that be an example of memory conflict?) but also thread 5 has to access bank 4.

Could you please explain to me this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that a *bank* is not the same thing as a *word* or location in shared memory.  A bank refers collectively to all words in shared memory that satisfy a certain address pattern condition.

In general, shared memory bank conflicts can be avoided if all accesses from a warp (or half-warp in cc 1.x) go to separate banks.  These accesses need not be in warp order, i.e. they can be scrambled, as long as the request from each thread targets a separate bank.

The above description covers every arrow in your diagram except those arrows pointing to bank 5.

If we had no other information, then multiple arrows targetting a single bank would indicate a potential bank conflict.

However, there is an exception, when not only are the accesses targetting the same bank, but they are targetting the *same word in memory*.  When multiple shared memory requests target the *same word in memory*, then the shared memory system has a broadcast mechanism to take the data contained in that word, and service it to all the requesting threads, in a single cycle.

From the documentation(http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared-memory-1-x):

> Shared memory features a broadcast mechanism whereby a 32-bit word can be read and broadcast to several threads simultaneously when servicing one memory read request. This reduces the number of bank conflicts when several threads read from an address within the same 32-bit word.

Comment: On cc 1.x devices when some of the threads of a half-warp (**not** necessarily all of them) access the same address and **every** other thread of that half-warp accesses an address in other bank the broadcast is applied.

On the other hand if two or more groups of threads access the same address in the same bank (different for each group) the broadcast will **not** be used.

On cc 2.x and higher there can be any number of conflicting accesses of this type and the broadcast will work for all of them. 

Am I correct, or is my understanding still off ?

Comment: Yes, I believe your understanding is correct.  It is pretty much spelled out that way if you compare the descriptions of shared memory access in the programming guide between the cc1.x case and the cc2.x case (for example, cc2.x description: "(and unlike for devices of compute capability 1.x, multiple words can be broadcast in a single transaction)").  In the particular case of the diagram captured in this question, there is only one address location that needs "broadcasting", so I would not expect a difference in behavior in this respect between cc1.x and cc2.x, for this case.